# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: angular

code:-
1. sections: Departments[];

```
let sectionCount:number;
    sectionCount = +this.sections.find(x =>x.sections).sections;
```

Error.

```
 error TS2345: Argument of type '(this: void, x: Departments) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Departments, index: number, obj: Departments[]) => boolean'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: sections are number type - after running the application it is showing the - Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: Not sure if you really have `sections.sections` but It does not seem like the immediate issue is with the return value of the entire expression, but the problem is with the find's predicate function's return type. Looks like `sections` is of type number, find predicate function should return a boolean value.. you can coerce the `sections` prop or apply some conditional to it.  For example: `this.sections.find(x =>!!x.sections).sections` or `this.sections.find(x =>x.sections > 0).sections`. Even though practically it would work in javascript, typescript wants explicit type matching

Answer (score 1):

If you are interpreting from the error  `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'` it is not related to `sectionCount`.

As the error says, find() method has to return a boolean value instead of a number -

try something like -

```
sectionCount = this.sections.find(x => {
  return x.sections > 0;
}).sections;
```

Comment: Am not sure if this will work either as his return type for  sectionCount is supposed to be a number.

Comment: he mentioned "sections are number type" in comment